# How to read couchbase-lite log files using cbl-log Tool

Tags: ionic3, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am trying to read the logs that have been generated by my ionic cordova app which uses a enterprise offline storage plugin(v1.0.6) for cbl-lite 2.5  by ionic.

I have downloaded the cbl-log tool for windows using command,extracted it and installed the package:

> "Invoke-WebRequest
>   https://packages.couchbase.com/releases/couchbase-lite-log/2.5.0/couchbase-lite-log-2.5.0-windows.zip
>   -OutFile couchbase-lite-log-2.5.0-windows.zip"

But after trying the command to read the logs of "cbl_info_1585897723799.cbllog" file:
 ".\cbl-log.exe logcat cbl_info_1585897723799.cbllog  FOLDER_OUTPUT_PATH"
 using cbl tool i am getting below error as:

[image]

I am referring "https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.5/csharp.html" link,

If this tool cannot read the .cbllog extension file, then can anyone please suggest how should I read this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this after regenerating logs & providing the output file path.
Important things to note:

1. cbl-log logcat tool only converts a binary log file to text.
2. Provide the output file name with its path.
3. check the input file size, to make sure file is not corrupted.